# view.py got an unexpected keyword argument topic_id #p

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm trying to fix this view keep getting this error message,
'''
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
topics() got an unexpected keyword argument 'topic_id'
Exception Location: /home/draco/shola/learning_log/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
'''

view.py

```
def topics(request):

    topics = TopicModel.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics' : topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html',context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = TopicModel.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topic':topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topic.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index.html'),


url(r'^topics/$',views.topics, name='topics.html'),
url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)\$',views.topics,name='topic.html')
```

models.py

```
    from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):

    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,
                              on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.text) >50:

            return  self.text[:50]+"....."

        else:
            return self.text
```

Template

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content%}
<p>Topics</p>

<ul>
    {%for topic in topics%}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic.html' topic.id %}">{{topic}}</a>
    </li>
    {%empty%}
    <li>no topic have been added yet</li>
    {%endfor%}
    
</ul>
{%endblock content%}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The last line in your `urls.py` should be `views.topic`, not `topics`.

Answer (score 0):

Error in this line of code:

```
 url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)\$',views.topics,name='topic.html')

 url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)\$',**views.topics**,name='topic.html')
```

should be corrected for

```
 url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)\$',**views.topic**,name='topic.html')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).